# Does Intellij maintain list of recent actions done by Developer?

Tags: intellij-idea

Does Intellij maintain list of recent actions done by Developer - CREATE, EDIT, COPY, SEARCH, DELETE etc?

The reason for asking is that, I had accidentally created a file in a directory, which turned out to create issues.

If I could have tracked it out, then I could have saved some time.

Comment: The `Recently Changed Files` (Cmd+Shift+E) action is maybe helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create, edit, and delete are all tracked by Local History. Each file maintains it's own, you can also view it at a directory level, such as if you want to see deleted files or all changes in sub folders. This can be viewed by right clicking on the file or directory in IntelliJ and selecting *Local History > Show History*.
Local history is cleared with your cache, so if you ever have a need to clear it you will lose this information for all files.

As for copy actions, there is a history of those (default 5), viewable by default with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> (or OS equivalent). You can increase the limit under *Settings > Editor > General - "Maximum .. keep in clipboard"*.
This history is lost on a restart of the program though, and only tracks items that were copied in the editor itself.

And for search actions, in any search input there is a dropdown arrow that will show the most recently used searches. However, the order changes as you reuse items, and it is shared across all search inputs.
This history is kept between restarts, but likely lost on clearing the caches as well.